# Error using module bzip2

Tags: ruby

I'm running into problems building bzip2-ruby. 
Here is the error I am getting while building it...
Can someone help me understand what's going on?

```
/tmp/ruby/bin/gem -v
2.6.8


/tmp/ruby/bin/ruby -v
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-linux]

In file included from bzip2.c:5:
/tmp/ruby/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/backward/rubyio.h:2:2: warning: #warning use "ruby/io.h" instead of "rubyio.h"
bzip2.c:6:21: error: version.h: No such file or directory
bzip2.c: In function ‘bz_find_struct’:
```

Comment: This kind of error usually happens when you are trying to compile a gem and you don't have the C headers required to do this. Please, check your distribution to see if you have some package named bzip2-dev or something like that. If you don't have installed, please install and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The error is described in https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby/issues/19 and [fixed in the master branch](https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby/commit/46939f3521eed0f12157c3a20a1a077cf51d17d1) of the gem.

Unfortunately, the fix is not yet released and given that the issue is now almost 4 years old, I'd wager the guess that it won't be released anymore. If you still want to use the gem, you can force to use the version directly from github by adding this to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'bzip2-ruby', git: 'https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby.git'
```

Generally, it is probably a good idea to switch to a gem which is actually maintained. A quick google search pointed e.g. to https://github.com/philr/bzip2-ffi.

Comment: I tried both the solution provided by you but no luck.

Comment: My Gemfile is like this:

 cat Gemfile
source :gemcutter

gemspec
source gem 'bzip2-ruby', git: 'https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby.git'